# Setup Multiple Port on Wamp Server to use on Localtunnel Link

Tags: php, apache, server, wampserver, wamp64

So I was taking a course online then I needed to run npm localtunnel on my pc and localtunnel was installed and I was given a unique link to share with my client to access the beta stage of his project.

but that link redirects to my wamp root directory exposing my server.

How can I use a different port for the root directory and different port for another purpose like to share the beta state of projects?

port 80 is my root
I want to set 8080 for other purposes.

Thanks

Comment: I think what you need is to put your other projects into Virtual Hosts